# Add a Filter to a Wordpress Plugin's Class Function

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a bit of HTML right before a bit of plugin HTML without editing the actual plugin.

The function appears within their class NavigationBar.

```
class NavigationBar {
    public static function get_navigation_bar( $options ) {
        // THE CODE
        return $html;
    }
}
```

I would like to add a filter in my functions.php kinda like this:

```
function get_navigation_bar_with_ad( $html ) {
    $html = '<div>This appears before the nav bar.</div>' . $html;
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_navigation_bar', 'get_navigation_bar_with_ad' );
```

Is there an easy way to do this other than adding the HTLM into the plugin's code? I would prefer to avoid that so that future updates don't break the code. Thanks!

---

In the contructor that uses the `NavigationBar::get_navigation_bar( $options )` function they add actions and filters to the $html object.

```
add_filter( 'tps_the_content_after_current_slide', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Content::filter_content_after_current_slide', 10, 2 );
```

If I could prepend to this filter I think I would get my desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the plugin provides a filter/action itself, it is possible yes, but it doesnt seem like it does.
You could regognize it at a "apply_filter()" or "do_action" function like

```
$html = apply_filter(...);
```

I would suggest you to use jQuery and manipulate the html like following:

```
jQuery('#idOfPluginHtml').prepend("<div>Your HTML</div>");
```

thx to DubVader: prepend is right

nice @LucyTurtle that i could help you. Ill add your final solution to my comment in case somebody needs exactly this:
**Solution:**

```
function get_navigation_bar_with_ad( $html ) {
    return $html . '<div>This will appear above the nav bar.</div>';
}
add_filter( 'tps_the_content_after_current_slide', 'get_navigation_bar_with_ad' );
```

Comment: I agree with the jQuery approach, probably the simplest.  However, you would want to use .prepend() - since you want it before the other element,  instead of .append() - which would place it after.

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to avoid jquery in this case, but I will use it as a last ditch effort. Thanks!~

Comment: They do apply other filters to the html object in the content contructor. I will add some details to my question

Comment: What you just added is a "add_filter" you cant hook into that. Please add the code which comes before the "return $html;" inside "public static function get_navigation_bar". If there is no "apply_filter or do_action" they didnt provide filters for devs

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Using @Tonno's answer I found a hook that I could filter. I added this filter to my `functions.php`

```
function get_navigation_bar_with_added_code( $html ) {
    return $html . '<div>This will appear above the nav bar.</div>';
}
add_filter( 'tps_the_content_after_current_slide', 'get_navigation_bar_with_added_code' );
```